# Opening PDF in a browser with Github Pages

Tags: web, github, github-pages

I am using GitHub Pages to host my website. I have a PDF file that I want visitors to be able to open directly in a browser. But when I upload the PDF file to GitHub Pages and link to it it opens in GitHub's viewer. Is there any way to open the PDF in a browser? I do not want to upload the document to dropbox or Google Drive as these services are not available in certain countries.

Using a raw URL would lead to download. But I would like to have the file open in the browser.

Comment: How did you link to the file? If you're loading it directly from a GitHub repository you'll need to use the "raw" link.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out. Using raw would lead to a download, which is not what I would like to see. I want to have the file open directly in the browser.

Comment: Sorry, my previous link was misleading. I have written a proper answer below, and I'll delete the comment referring to `site.static_files`.

Comment: No, your answer is basically just copy pasting.

Comment: i agree with the so recommendation. But I think you are understanding it wrong. Providing contexts means explaining, not copy pasting.

Comment: I don't get how to avoid downloading...

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 48):

Suppose your personal website is hosted in a Github page as follows:

```
https://username.github.io
```

The repository should be name as **username.github.io**. If you have a pdf file named **document.pdf** and you place it in the directory **folder** then you should be able to open it directly in the browser through the following link:

```
https://username.github.io/folder/document.pdf
```

To allow the user to open the pdf in a new window in the browser, you may use the following HTML, where "PDF" points to the link:

```
<a href="username.github.io/folder/document.pdf" target="_blank">PDF.</a>
```

Comment: This should probably replace the accepted answer, as of 2019. It is much simpler, and words perfectly.

Comment: This gets me 404 file not found. I am trying to access this file: https://github.com/ethanabrooks/ethanabrooks.github.io/blob/master/static/CV.pdf using this link: https://ethanabrooks.github.io/static/CV.pdf

Comment: I think this solution doesn't work anymore for new files!! But still working for old files.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... well i do not want to load it down i want to open it in a new window 

<a href="username.github.io/folder/document.pdf" target="_blank">PDF.</a>


how to do this?: 

<a href="https://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/bitstream/JRC117910/jrc117910_dihs_survey_jrc_report_pubsy_online.pdf" target="_blank">PDF-Text.</a>

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Simple workaround: add https:// before the address of your file, such that ```<a href="https://username.github.io/folder/document.pdf" target="_blank">PDF.</a>``` Then the link should direct users to your file

Answer (score 18):

Instead of loading your PDF directly from GitHub, include it in your GitHub Pages branch as a static file. This can be done by simply [putting the file somewhere in your source tree](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/):

> Every other directory and file except for those listed above—such as  `css` and `images` folders, `favicon.ico` files, and so forth—will be copied verbatim to the generated site. There are plenty of [sites already using Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/sites/) if you’re curious to see how they’re laid out.

So put the PDF somewhere that makes sense, for example in `pdfs/foo.pdf`.

To make a link to this PDF work both locally and on GitHub Pages, [Jekyll recommends the following](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure) (note especially point #2):

> Sometimes it’s nice to preview your Jekyll site before you push your `gh-pages` branch to GitHub. However, the subdirectory-like URL structure GitHub uses for Project Pages complicates the proper resolution of URLs. Here is an approach to utilizing the GitHub Project Page URL structure (`username.github.io/project-name/`) whilst maintaining the ability to preview your Jekyll site locally.
>
> 1. In `_config.yml`, set the `baseurl` option to `/project-name` – note the leading slash and the **absence** of a trailing slash.
> 2. When referencing JS or CSS files, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/css.css` – note the slash immediately following the variable (just before “path”).
> 3. When doing permalinks or internal links, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}` – note that there is **no** slash between the two variables.
> 4. Finally, if you’d like to preview your site before committing/deploying using `jekyll serve`, be sure to pass an **empty string** to the `--baseurl` option, so that you can view everything at `localhost:4000` normally (without `/project-name` at the beginning): `jekyll serve --baseurl ''`

So now you can link to your PDF with `{{ site.baseurl }}/pdfs/foo.pdf`.

Comment: Hello dear Chris,  thanks for all  and of course for the explanation... well i do not want to load it down i want to open it in a new window 

<a href="username.github.io/folder/document.pdf" target="_blank">PDF.</a>

how to do this?: 

<a href="https://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/bitstream/JRC117910/jrc117910_dihs_survey_jrc_report_pubsy_online.pdf" target="_blank">PDF-Text.</a>

Answer (score 9):

It's very easy to display Pdf in browser from Github static page, for that you need approach following process,

1. Make the static website/repository using your Github username, for example, if the username is **sumanbogati** then repository would be **sumanbogati.github.io**
2. Put the desired pdf in that repository
3. Now locate the Url of Pdf wherever you want

For example, to display pdf in Html web page

```
<embed src="https://sumanbogati.github.io/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
```

This is an [instant demo](https://sumanbogati.github.io/how-to-upload-pdf/pdfembeded.html).

Comment: I upload a pdf to my repository, however the link won't work, for example, https://my.github.io/my.pdf. Is there any other steps needed?

Comment: I figured out. Need to create another directory with html contains `<embed src="https://my.github.io/my.pdf" type="application/pdf" />`

Comment: You repository `my.github.io/my.pdf` is not configured, have you created the repository with GitHub username ? As in my case repo is `sumanbogati.github.io` and username is `sumanbogati`.

Comment: or just use anchor tag instead of embed

Comment: This is a very elegant solution and it works great on desktop. However, the `embed` doesn't work very well on mobile (tried on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari). It only displays the first page of the PDF and it doesn't allow scrolling. Therefore, I would suggest combining this with [ruifgmonteiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54531930/948768). In the Markdown file, include:

`If the embedded PDF is not displayed properly, <a href="https://my.github.io/my.pdf" target="_blank">please click here.</a>
<embed src="https://my.github.io/my.pdf" width="1000px" height="800px" />`

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through most of the answers in this section however most of them are hard to figure out or too vague to understand what is happening. There is a simpler way to do this, so in order to display a Pdf file in a browser from Github here is the process:

**Step 1:** Make the static website/repository using your Github username for example, if the username is `winterishere` then repository would be `winterishere.github.io`

**Step 2:** Put the desired pdf in that repository and add an `index.html` file in the same location as the pdf file eg: `resume.pdf`.

**Step 3:** Open the `index.html` and add the embed tag to it below:

```
<embed src="https://yourusername.github.io/filename.pdf" width="100%" height="850px"/>
```

in my example the file the code would be:

```
 <embed src="https://winterishere.github.io/resume.pdf" width="100%" height="850px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Docs viewer with a URL like:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={link_to_pdf}
```

e.g.

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://username.github.io/folder/document.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `index.html` use this 
`<embed src="/Repo_Name/Resume_Name.pdf" width="100%" height="745px" />`

This worked for me, [check](https://richard937.github.io/resume/) 
** Only good for Laptop view

Comment: What should I do to show the pdf properly from all devices including mobile browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Make an file called `index.html` in your repository with only the following code in it:

```
<iframe src="./yourfile.pdf" width="100% height=100%">
</iframe>
```

Your pdf file needs to be in the same directory as your "index.html" file. This means that both your pdf file and index.html file need to be uploaded to your git hub repository. Then you can use github pages pointed to your "index.html" file to display the pdf in a browser.

Using the `<iframe>` tag is better now because the `<embed>` tag is no longer supported in some browsers/devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to try the below method as it worked for me on my Github pages.

We need two files:
a)Resume.html
b)Resume.pdf

Put these two files in the primary working directory. These files must be in the same directory as your "index.html" file.

Add the following to the HTML file you are working in (let's say its index.html):

```
   <li><a href="./Resume.html" target="_blank">
   <p>resume</p>
   </a></li>
```

Then, add the following to the resume.html you just created:

```
 <embed src="./Resume.pdf" type="application/pdf" width=100% height=850px />
```

What it'll do:
After the primary HTML (i.e. index.html) is loaded and you click the resume text present in it, a new window should open and load resume.html, and this resume.html will load Resume.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. put the file in `https://my.github.io/files/paper.pdf`
2. add link `<a href="https://my.github.io/files/paper.pdf">mypdf</a>`
3. push the changes.

Now if you click the mypdf link, it should open in browser directly.

Answer (score -1):

Place the PDF file in a folder like; www.website/pdf/example.pdf this will stop the file downloading outside of the root directory.

The steps are:

**1.** Create a new file in main directory.

**2.** Name file /pdf/ and save it.

**3.** Upload example.pdf file to this folder

*Result::* PDF is viewable at; www.website/pdf/example.pdf

**4.** Optional step to avoid the .pdf URL. Create a index.html file in this folder and create a blank html file with PDF embed tag:

Answer (score -2):

You can link it this way

`<a target='_blank' href={require('path/to/pdf/file')}>PDF Doc</a>`

Then, when you push to GitHub page, you will see your pdf file path as so

`https://userName.github.io/repoName/static/media/pdfFileName.hashNumber.pdf`

I believe it works if you import the file instead of using require as well but I haven't tested with that.