# Embeded PDF Blocked in Github Pages

Tags: github-pages

I am trying to embed a PDF viewer in my github pages site, so visitors can see my CV and download it. I don't want a hyperlink to the pdf, but to actually have it interactive in the page (like [this](https://sumanbogati.github.io/how-to-upload-pdf/pdfembeded.html)).

I'm embedding with the line:

```html
<embed src="https://github.com/username/username.github.io/blob/master/CV.pdf" class="application/pdf" width = "100%" height="100%" />
```

But when I navigate to the page (username.github.io/cv/, it only displays the error:

"Blocked by Content Security Policy

An error occurred during a connection to github.com.

Firefox prevented this page from loading in this way because the page has a content security policy that disallows it."

If I try and open the page in Chromium, it's just blank.

I've tried everything described here:
[Opening PDF in a browser with Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745981/opening-pdf-in-a-browser-with-github-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `<embed>`, all browsers will show you a CSP error, Chromium will probably have an error thrown in the dev console. For more info check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors)

I'll assume you have an index.html page which have your `<embed>` line above.

The issue is that you are embedding a link to the github page that has CV.pdf, i.e. you added a link to another `HTML`. Instead of doing so, you need to link it to the raw pdf inside your `src`. You can get the correct ***url*** by going to the Github page that has your CV.pdf, right click on *Download* and then *Copy Link Address* and use it in your `src`.